# Сохранить страницу в html

Tags: php

Нужно сохранить страницу по url в html-файл.
Сохраняю так:

```
function savel( $url, $file_namel ) {
        $data = fopen( $file_namel,"w+");
        fputs( $data, urlHttp( $url ) );
        fclose( $data );
    }
function urlHttp( $url ) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
        $file = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $file;
    }
```

На некоторый сайтах выдаёт 302. Т.е. сохранять такую страницу смысла не имеет. Как обойти 302. Что не так с curl

Comment: это код редиректа

Comment: Да. Это я понимаю. У меня первый url проходит с ответом 200, следующее обращение с ответом 302. Вот как это обойти ума не дам.

Comment: выставлял даже таймауты. Результат всё равно 302. Ждать приходится примерно 30-40 минут, чтобы получить 200.

Comment: вам нужно проверять, куда редиректит страница, и сохранять страницу с url редиректа. Это банально может быть редирект с http на https

Comment: Нет. переадресация на страницу с авторизацией. Сейчас вот подумал прокси впихнуть в curl. может поможет....

Comment: @Алекс, уточните, вам нужно отсекать страницы с переадресацией, или скачивать те страницы, на которые эта переадресация ведет? Или у вас какая-то проблема уже с авторизацией?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не могу получить контент повторно. Если первый раз я получаю содержимое по url, то второй раз по этому же url я контент получить не могу - 302. Могу только через 30-40 минут. Т.е., видимо получаю бан на это время.

Comment: Пробовал добавлять в curl прокси. Но как-то не помогло.